# Formatting datetime in input type date with Angular ngModel

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date-formatting

I have this input that is a type date and my 'dateOfDiagnosis' is a string coming from the controller, which includes the time, like this

> "2010-09-08T00:00:00"

```html
<input type="date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="claim.claimData.dateOfDiagnosis" (ngModelChange)="markDirty()" name="dateOfDiagnosis">
```

The error/warning in the console says

> The specified value "2010-09-08T00:00:00" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

So I tried to slice the string like this

```
[(ngModel)]="claim.claimData.dateOfDiagnosis.slice(0,10)"
```

but that threw a bunch of erros.

Is there a way to format it (remove the time) on the html side without doing anything in the .ts file?
Or do something else to get this to work without doing anything in the .ts file?

The error says:

> Error: Template parse errors:
>   Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 44 in [claim.claimData.dateOfDiagnosis.slice(0,10)=$event] in ng:///AppModule/WmacComponent.html@60:92 ("/label>
>             ]claim.claimData.dateOfDiagnosis.slice(0,10)"  (ngModelChange)="markDirty()" name="dateOfDiagnosis">

Comment: Have you tried `substring` instead of `slice`? If you told us the errors, it would be easier to help...

Comment: I updated my post with the error

Comment: I just tried substring and it looks like the error is the same

Comment: Oh, right, since you’re using 2-way binding it tries to set the value, and neither function can be on the left side of an assignment.

Comment: You’d have to fix it on the controller or data source side.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `ngModel` is two-way binding. Applying a method like `slice` works when you're passing a value down, but not when it's getting passed back up. Expanded, your `ngModel` binding looks like this:

```
[ngModel]="claim.claimData.dateOfDiagnosis.slice(0,10)" 
    (ngModelChange)="claim.claimData.dateOfDiagnosis.slice(0,10)=$event"
```

The line

```
claim.claimData.dateOfDiagnosis.slice(0,10)=$event
```

Doesn't make sense, and is what is triggering your error.

There are a few ways you can get around this, depending on the specific requirements of the context.

If the  `dateOfDiagnosis` field is not required to be in the `2010-09-08T00:00:00` format, you could simply call

```
this.claim.claimData.dateOfDiagnosis = this.claim.claimData.dateOfDiagnosis.slice(0,10);
```

Where it is set, or you could use a different variable to track the date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, and add the `T00:00:00` when you assign it back to `claim.claimData.dateOfDiagnosis`.

You could even use the expended form of `ngModel` to do it all in place. i.e:

```
[ngModel]="claim.claimData.dateOfDiagnosis.slice(0,10)" 
    (ngModelChange)="claim.claimData.dateOfDiagnosis = $event + 'T00:00:00'"
```